# Configure Sublime Text build system for Scala?

Tags: scala, sublimetext3, build-system

I'm trying to configure a build system for Scala with SublimeText, but I am having some difficulty.  I have tried both of the following:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "scala",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}

{
    "cmd": ["/path/to/bin/scala", "$file_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala",
    "shell": true
}
```

Both of these attempts produce the same failed output - it seems to start up the interactive Scala shell rather than running my script.  Any advice?

Comment: I found I had to use `"working_dir": "${file_path}"` to run individual scripts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer that worked turned out to be very close to the second answer - apparently I'm not supposed to open up a new shell.  If someone can clarify when to set `"shell": true` in the comments, that would be really helpful.

```
{
    "cmd": ["/path/to/bin/scala", "$file_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

Comment: Why `working_dir` is set to `"${project_path:${folder}}"` instead of `"${project_path}"`?

Comment: I couldn't find any good tutorial on how to write build systems properly in the docs - tbh I haven't really found thorough sublime documentation anywhere.  This must have been what I could cobble together at the time.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Program Files (x86)/scala/bin/scala.bat", "$file_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

This worked for me.
replace C:/ with your own path.

Answer (score 1):

In Packages/Scala/Scala.sublime-build, add this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["[PATH TO SCALA]", "$file"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

Replace the [PATH TO SCALA] with the path of where scala interpreter is located in your system. Do a "which scala" to find out.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
{
    "cmd": ["scala", "$file"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala",
    "shell": true
}
```

given you set the system PATH thing:

```
Variable: %PATH%
Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin
```

Comment: Yes, it works, the most important part here is `"shell": true`, without which, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I didn't install Scala or SublimeText, I just used the zip. But this code worked for me to compile the .scala files from SublimeText3 on Windows.

```
{"cmd": ["C:/Scala/scala-2.13.3/bin/scalac.bat", "$file"],
"working_dir": "$file_path",
"selector": "source.scala",
"encoding":"utf-8",
"file_patterns": "*.scala",
"shell": true}
```

You can create it or [download it](https://github.com/NemoSbrin/AportesVariados/blob/master/SublimeText/Scala.sublime-build) and put it in the directory Sublime Text Build 3 ###\Data\Packages\User

Answer (score 0):

### Build System For Scala :

##### OSX - (Mac)

**Use the below:**

```
{
    "cmd": ["/opt/homebrew/bin/scala", "$file_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

**Path to delete the build:**

`/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages/User`