# How to use the SublimeSBT plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, sublimetext3

I'm trying to run a simple Scala program in Sublime text using the [SublimeSBT](https://github.com/jarhart/SublimeSBT) plugin, but I can't seem to get it to work. Firstly, following http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html I ran the command

```
sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
```

This creates a directory called `hello`. If I `cd` to that directory and launch sublime using `subl .`, and bring up the command palette, I don't see the commands prefixed with `SBT:` which should be there according to the SublimeSBT usage instructions:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that I installed the plugin as it shows up as `SublimeSBT` in `Sublime Text` -> `Preferences` -> `Package Settings`. Can anyone explain why this is not working?

Comment: Does the Sublime console contain anything that looks like an error message regarding `sbt` during startup?

Answer (score 1):

What I wanted was to simply run simple scripts (like https://scalafiddle.io/) and I solved this problem by

```
brew install scala
```

and adding the following build system as `Scala.sublime-build` (cf. [Configure Sublime Text build system for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595858/configure-sublime-text-build-system-for-scala)):

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/scala", "$file_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.scala"
}
```

Now when you press Cmd + B it will run the script (see screen grab below).

[image]